# Использование многопоточности для парсера

Tags: php, многопоточность

Здравствуйте.

Появилась потребность в использовании многопоточности для парсера, не могу точно сказать про поддержку posix решения на хостинге, поэтому хотел бы узнать, есть ли какое-нибудь более грамотное решение, чем реализация с помощью CURL?

Вот на хабре есть такой [пост](http://habrahabr.ru/post/75454/), но как обернуть отдельную функцию, а не вызывать файл?

Comment: https://github.com/dalehurley/PHP-Process-Manager вот, нашел интересный класс, что скажите?

Comment: попробовал его, нельзя передать аргументы( да и парсер не завелся с ним

Comment: https://github.com/kriswallsmith/spork

Comment: микроскопом сложно забивать гвозди. ЗАЗ-968М сложно выиграть гонку Париж-Дакар. ПХП не предназначен для многопоточности.

Comment: Видимо, никак. Насколько я понял, на самом деле там нигде нет никакой *многопоточности* (скажем, в смысле `pthread_create()`), а речь идет о параллельном выполнении *процессов* (в смысле `fork()`, с последующим `exec()`).

Comment: @avp есть, но в качестве экспериментального расширения pthreads.

Comment: @Etki, наверное, все-таки *экспериментального расширения PHP*, а не [pthreads](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads)

Comment: @avp, нет, наверное в качестве экспериментального расширения pthreads. Оно называется так же. Это же PHP.

Comment: Интересно.

 И что же туда (к Posix Threads API) нового добавили, чтобы стало можно (или удобно?) реализовывать потоки в  PHP?

Comment: @avp не, underlying code - все те же функции си. Просто расширение носит название pthreads, аналогично тому, что обычно именуют под pthreads. Саму сишку расширение никак не меняет.

Comment: Можеть быть, вам следует еще посмотреть в сторону Gearman - http://habrahabr.ru/post/123451/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем за оставленные комментарии. Присмотрелся к PHP-Process-Manager снова, добавил функцию поиска php bin path и автопостановку для cli режима php.ini. Все работает в 3 потока замечательно. Остальные решения очень громоздкие и требуют полного вникания в наборы методов.